# shell with xml, grep and sed

Tags: xml, shell, sed, grep

after searching a lot for solutions to my problem I finally must ask it and try to get some great answers

So, I have an xml file in the likes

```
< trigger name="ECUReset" value="0x11">
...
< /trigger>
< trigger name="ClearDTC" value="0x14">
...
< /trigger>
```

I want to parse this with shell script and to retrieve the `trigger name` and it's `value` in a associative array, or something close to `perl hashes`

The tools that I have available on the machine are only `grep` and `sed`, I don't have `perl` or `awk`

What I managed to get now is

```
trigger_name=$(sed -n '/trigger_name=/ s/[^\x22]*\x22\(\x22*\)//p' $FILENAME)
```

but that doesn't return what I wanted

I cannot use perl, though I would definitely like to because I'm a perl dev, and also no awk or something else, just shell with sed and grep.

Comment: If you're not looking for a perl solution, why did you include the perl tag?

Comment: @Dmitry, nope, unfortunately shell, sed and grep are the only tools that I can use,

Comment: can you paste an expected output?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `cut` utility:

```
$ grep "< trigger" test.xml \
> | cut --delimiter=" " --fields=3,4 \
> | cut --delimiter='"' --fields=2,4 --output-delimiter=" : "
ECUReset : 0x11
ClearDTC : 0x14
```

Answer (score 0):

does this work for you? (just with sed)

```
sed -rn '/trigger name/{s/.*trigger name="([^"]*)" value="([^"]*)".*$/\1=\2/g;p}' file
```

test

```
kent$  echo '< trigger name="ECUReset" value="0x11">
...
< /trigger>
< trigger name="ClearDTC" value="0x14">
...
< /trigger>'|sed -rn '/trigger name/{s/.*trigger name="([^"]*)" value="([^"]*)".*$/\1=\2/g;p}'                                                                              
ECUReset=0x11
ClearDTC=0x14
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep 'trigger name' your_file| cut -d'"' -f 2,4|sed 's/\"/ /g'
```

tested:

```
>cat temp
< trigger name="ECUReset" value="0x11">
...
< /trigger>
< trigger name="ClearDTC" value="0x14">
...
< /trigger>
> grep 'trigger name' temp | cut -d'"' -f 2,4 | sed 's/\"/ /g'
ECUReset 0x11
ClearDTC 0x14
```

Answer (score 0):

Just using `sed`:

```
# names
$ sed -n 's/< trigger name="\([^"]*\).*/\1/p' file
ECUReset
ClearDTC

# values
$ sed -n 's/< trigger.*value="\([^"]*\).*/\1/p' file
0x11
0x14

# both
$ sed -n 's/.*< trigger name="\([^"]*\).*value="\([^"]*\).*/\1 \2/p' file
ECUReset 0x11
ClearDTC 0x14
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replies, but for some reason none of those commands return something

Comment: The scripts are portable so will work with any implementation of `sed` so it means the example you posted is different from your actual file. Makes sure you example represents you file correct so I can update the regex accordingly.